# Prestashop 1.7.X friendly url whithout category name

Tags: prestashop, friendly-url

I would like to have the URL: demo.com/product-name

Where we have (the standard): demo.com/en/home/18-product-name

We will remove Category (as we have same product in many categories) and ID from URL.

We modified the route: {category:/}{id}{-:id_product_attribute}-{rewrite}{-:ean13}

to: {rewrite}

Does NOT work. The URL in lists of products is OK (the new), but when pressed, the page is a 404 error.

Can you help me configure this SEO option correctly?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some fields (as you can see underneath the input field) are manditory (like: id, rewrite and id_product_attribute).

So change it to (for example):

{id}-{rewrite}{-:id_product_attribute}-{-:ean13}

And you'll be good to go.

You can also buy a clean url module to remove the id's.